# Multiple processes write to the same file (C)

Tags: c, fork

There is a program (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, a single-core processor):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(){

    mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR;
    int i = 0, fd, pid;
    unsigned char pi1 = 0x33, pi2 = 0x34;
    if((fd = open("res", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, mode)) < 0){

        perror("open error");
        exit(1);
    }



    if((pid = fork()) < 0){

       perror("fork error");
       exit(1);
    }

    if(pid == 0) {


       if(write(fd, &pi2, 1) != 1){

           perror("write error");
           exit(1);
       }  
    }else{

       if(write(fd, &pi1, 1) != 1){

           perror("write error");
           exit(1);
       }  
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is to open the file for writing, then going fork. The position at which there will be a record total for both processes. The strange thing is that if you run the program, it's output to a file "res" is not constant: I have infuriated then 34 then 4 then 3. The question is why such a conclusion? (After all, if the position is shared, then the conclusion must be either 34 or 43.).

In my suspicion, the process is interrupted in the function write, when he found a position in which to write.

Comment: *I have infuriated then 34 then 4 then 3* What ?

Answer (score 4):

When you spawn multiple processes with fork() there is no way to tell in which order they will be executed. It's up to the operating systems scheduler to decide.

So having multiple processes write to the same file is a recipe for disaster.

Regarding the question why sometimes one of the two numbers gets omitted: write first writes the data and then it increments the file pointer. I think it could be possible that the thread control changes in exactly that moment so that the second thread writes before the file position was updated. So it overwrites the data the other process just wrote.

Comment: The problem here is something else: I would expect the output 34 or 43. But sometimes appears just 3 or 4.
How does it happen?

Comment: I asked you WHY it happend. I'm interesting why it happen.

Comment: Just rethink your *shared* data synchronization once more.

Comment: Want an answer to why sometimes the output is 3 or 4. At what point does one process overwrites the data of another?

Comment: Is it possible to stop the process when it executes the kernel and is not left in a dream?

Answer (score 3):

I run your program several times,and the result is "34" or "43".
 So i have write a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..500}
    do
            ./your_program
            for line in $(cat res) 
            do
                    echo "$line" 
            done
    done
```

,and run your program 500 times. As we can see,it get '3' or '4' some times( aboat 20 times in 500)。
How we can explain this? 
The answer is that:
when we fork() a child process,the child share the same file description and file state structure(which has the current file offset).
In normal,a process get offset=0 first,and write the first byte,and the offset=1;the other process get offset=1,and it will write the second byte.
But some times, **if the parent process get offset=0 from the file state structure ,and child get offset=0 at the same time**,a process write the first byte,and the other overwrite the first byte. The result will be "3" or "4" (depends on whether the parent write first or child ). Because they both write the first byte of the file.

[Fork and offset,see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636055/apuedoes-parent-and-child-share-the-same-file-offset-after-fork?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I think is happening.

- You `open` the file and you `fork`
- The parent gets to run first (similar stuff can happen if the child runs first)

  - The parent writes `3` and exits
  - The parent was the controlling process for the terminal so the kernel sends a SIGHUP to all members of the foreground group
- The default action of `SIGHUP` is to terminate the process so the child silently dies

A simple way to test this is to add sleep:

```
sleep(5); /* Somewhere in the child, right before you write. */
```

You'll see the child process dies instantaneously: **the write is never performed**.

Another way to test this is to ignore the `SIGHUP`, **before you fork**:

```
sigignore(SIGHUP);  /* Define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500 before including signal.h. */
/* You can also use signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN); */
```

You'll see the process now writes both digits to the file.

---

The overwriting hypothesis is unlikely. After `fork`, both processes share a link to the same file descriptor in a **system-wide table which also contains the file offset**.

Comment: SIGHUP signal is not sent because the connection to the terminal is not lost after the parent.

Comment: I too was surprised when I saw the dubbing. After all, they use a single entry in the table of open files.

Comment: @drlexa Try the suggestions in the answer :-)

Comment: I tried what you suggested: added ignore the signal SIGHUP. The problem is not solved. The file sometimes get just 3 or 4.

Comment: @drlexa Where did you ignore the signal ?

Comment: If you increase the number of processes (to fork and write in a loop), the file size is "res" will change after almost every run of the program. @cnicutar

Answer (score 1):

The standard says

**Write requests of {PIPE_BUF} bytes or less shall not be interleaved with data from other processes doing writes on the same pipe.**

Link - http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/write.html

The atomicity of write is only guaranteed in case of writing to a pipe for less than equal to PIPE_BUF and it is not specified for a regular file and we cannot assume that.

So in this case race condition is happening and that results in incorrect data for some runs.
(In my system also it is happening  after say  few thousand runs).

I think you should think of using mutex/semaphore/any other locking primitive to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need fork() exactly? fork() creates different process with different memory space (file descriptors and so on). Maybe pthreads would suit you? In case with pthreads you'll share the same fd for all processes. But anyways, you should really think about using mutexes in your project.

Comment: I expect the output 34 or 43. But sometimes appears just 3 or 4.
How does it happen?

Comment: I'm not sure for 100%, but perhaps some process overwrites data in your file, that has been put there by another process (the position in file is not correctly shared between two processes)

Comment: With this tool has only these two processes. They work with the same record in the table of open files. As one process could overwrite the data of another?

Comment: Want an answer to why sometimes the output is 3 or 4. At what point does one process overwrites the data of another?